# Why is this code using PyMuPDF not extracting all the images in a PDF?

Tags: python, image, pymupdf, pdf-scraping

I'm trying to extract images from an invoice for an equipment order and each time I run the code I only get 4 of 8 or 9 total photos on each page. Are there some PDFs that are just not compatible with some of PyMuPDF's functions?

```
def extract_images(model_nums, file):
    image_num = 0

    doc = fitz.open(file)

    # new directories that will hold images
    all_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "All Files")
    if not os.path.exists('All Files'):
        os.mkdir(all_path)
    if not os.path.exists(sport_id):
        os.mkdir(sport_path)

    for i in range(doc.page_count):
        print("Page: "+ str(i))
    
        images = doc.get_page_images(i)

        for img in images:  
            xref = img[0]
            pix = fitz.Pixmap(doc, xref)
            pix.save(f"{all_path}/{model_nums[image_num]}.jpg")
            pix = None

            image_num += 1
```

I've tried even searching up different code from other people that will just count the number of images and came up with the same issue.

Comment: "fitz" is the download name of PyMuPDF.

Comment: Multiple reasons for this apparent issue: (1) not everything that looks like an image is indeed one: it may be vector graphics - they do not have xrefs, don't appear in `get_images()` ,and thus cannot be extracted in this way (but by other means), (2) a PDF page may contain "inline" images, those also are not visible to a PDF's object inventory and do not appear in `get_images()`. PyMuPDF has solutions for this case too. But I assume you are complaining about missing vector graphics you are expecting.

Comment: It's weird because two of the images I want do get extracted properly but I'm missing the rest. Do you think the cases you mentioned could apply still?